# How Do I Reverse A Check-In/Deliver In Rational If The Component Has Accidentally Been Deleted?

Tags: rtc, ibm-rational

My most recent check in deleted my component from my local workspace. I can't explain, how, but it happened. I know how to reverse a delivery if the component exist within the component's history, but what if it is no longer in the workspace?

Comment: Could you try and checkout again the component in a new workspace, to check if it is still visible there?

Comment: I did. It's not there. I checked my personal check in/delivery history, and can only see the one thing I checked in, which wouldn't have done this, but the item that I was required to check in was nowhere in sight.

The component is totally gone from my local and I can't pull it into a new workspace.